# OSMDroid map not showing- small grey tiles only

Tags: android, android-maps, osmdroid, openstreetmap

```
        package com.andersoncouncil.osm_01;

    import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
    import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
    import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
    import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
    import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private TextView tv_sample;
        private MapView mapview_osm;
        private CustomItemizedOverlay item_overlay=null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tv_sample=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_sample);
            mapview_osm=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);

            ResourceProxy proxy=new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());      

            Drawable icon=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            int icon_height=icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
            int icon_width=icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            icon.setBounds(0,icon_height,icon_width,0);
            item_overlay=new CustomItemizedOverlay(icon, proxy);
            mapview_osm.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
            //mapview_osm.setUseDataConnection(true);
            mapview_osm.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);       
            mapview_osm.getOverlays().add(item_overlay);

            GeoPoint g1=new GeoPoint(5*1000000, 5*1000000);
            GeoPoint g2=new GeoPoint(50*100000, 70*1000000);
            item_overlay.addItem(g1,"point 1","point 1");
            item_overlay.addItem(g2, "point 2", "point 2"); 

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }


package com.andersoncouncil.osm_01;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapView;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> item_list=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker,
            ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
        super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String tittle, String snippets){
        OverlayItem item=new OverlayItem(tittle, snippets, p);
        item_list.add(item);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return item_list.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return item_list.size();
    }

}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OSM MAP EXAMPLE"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview_sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I ave attached my code above. Its just a simple implementation of OSMDroid, showing the launcher icon at two places. But my app is not sowing any maps. Its only showing grids(map grids, not actual places).

This programs manifest file is added below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andersoncouncil.osm_01"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.andersoncouncil.osm_01.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone up here, who knows the issue or can detect it please reply.

Comment: Are you running it in on emulators or on a physical device?

Comment: @Einar i am having the same problem and i am running it on emulator also i have tried with physical device both does not work

Answer (score 0):

what version of osmdroid? what is your target api? If you're using API 23 and up as the target, you have explicitly ask for permission from the user for internet access and file system storage. The latest osmdroid sample app has an example of what's needed. The android docs have a good example too.